# Sorting Multi-diminsional array

Tags: php

i am trying to sort `multi_diminsional` array using `array_multisort()`
but it does nothing to the original array.
here is my code :

```
foreach ($aOrderArticles as $oOrderArticle) {              
    $aOrderArticleExportData[$sUserId][$sArticleId]['lastname'] = $oOrder->oxorder__oxbilllname->value;
    $aOrderArticleExportData[$sUserId][$sArticleId]['firstname'] = $oOrder->oxorder__oxbillfname->value;
    $aOrderArticleExportData[$sUserId][$sArticleId]['title'] = $sTitle;
    $aOrderArticleExportData[$sUserId][$sArticleId]['amount'] += $oOrderArticle->oxorderarticles__oxamount->value;
}

$aSortedLastNames = array();
$aSortedFirstNames = array();
foreach($aOrderArticleExportData as $sUserId => $aUserData){
    foreach($aUserData as $aArticleData){
        $aSortedLastNames [] = $aArticleData ['lastname'];
        $aSortedFirstNames [] = $aArticleData ['firstname'];
    }
}

array_multisort($aSortedLastNames,SORT_ASC,$aSortedFirstNames,SORT_ASC,$aOrderArticleExportData);
```

Comment: The first loop is just overwriting the same elements of the array each time, since `$sUserid` and `$sArticleId` don't change in the loop.

Comment: No thats just a part of the code. Actually i wanted to show the array structure.

Comment: after the second loop the two arrays $aSortedLastNames and $aSortedFirstNames contains the first names and last names retrieved from the main array oOrderArticle

Comment: It's hard to know what's going wrong when you leave out relevant code. As it is, there's no 2-dimensional array to sort.

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by using one `foreach` loop and getting the current element.

The problem was that some users had more than one article so in our array, we had under same `userid` more than one record.

That means the number of elements in `$aSortedLastNames` and `$aSortedFirstNames` didn't match the number of elements of the main array, that's why `array_multisort` did not work.

Here is the new loop:

```php
$aSortedNames = array(); 

foreach ($aOrderArticleExportData as $sUserId => $aUserData) { 
    $aArticleData = current($aUserData);
    $aSortedNames[] = $aArticleData['lastname']. '_' . $aArticleData['firstname']; 
}

array_multisort($aSortedNames, SORT_ASC, $aOrderArticleExportData);
```